# React ScrollTop Issues

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've got a long list of items that are contained in a fixed height UL tag. Ideally, I'd like to scroll to the top of the list plus an offset (say 10px or so) when a list item is clicked.

I've got a ref set on my ListItem component that gets passed through the onClick event. Calling scrollIntoView() on my ref works as expected and scrolls to the top of the list, but trying to manually set a scrollTop value on my ref does nothing and seems to always stay stuck on 0.

Example shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/zsh2v1/sc9ux3dd/

```
onListItemClick(e, ref) {
    ref.scrollIntoView();
    ref.scrollTop += 10;
    console.log(ref.scrollTop); // why is this still zero?
}
```

So why doesn't this scrollTop value change? Is there a better way to go about setting this offset? Similar posts seem to point the finger at how your UL is styled, but I've already got a fixed height set on that UL. I've also tried throwing this in a setTimeout() call as some other posts recommended, but this also hasn't had any effect here.

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue too for some reasons, it didn't work. i fixed it by using jQuery

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

componentDidMount(){
       $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        let topOffset = $(this).scrollTop();

            console.log(topOffset);

        });
    }
```

when u move the scrollbar of your browser and check the console , the value changes.